Laravel pivot-to-pivot relationships
Laravel pivot-to-pivot relationships... good/bad idea? How to do in model?
I have 5 tables:
people
    id
places
    id
things
    id
people_place
    id
    people_id
    place_id
    "additional details"
people_thing
    id
    people_id
    thing_id
    "additional details"

I recently got the requirement to track which place a person's things are in. In this system, a person can have multiple instances of the same place with differing "addition details" and the things need to be linked to a specific people_place record. So my first idea was to add a people_place_id to the people_thing table, but now I'm not sure how to do that in the models. Y'all got any thoughts on this?

Unfortunately the format of your question means it will probably be closed for being "opinion based". Try to complete your design and then ask about any specific issue you are having implementing it. You say "... I'm not sure how to do that in the models" but have you tried anything?

I did ask for some opinions, but there is a real laravel question in there. I have made a relationship in the DB between two pivot tables. I need to know how to define that relationship in the models. I'm thinking I will have to make models for the pivot tables, but that feels wrong and I was hoping someone could point me to a niche laravel relationship function

The documentation has sections on Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models and using Custom Pivot Models and Incrementing IDs. So you can add an additional relationship to the pivot model.
You need a many-to-many relationship between people and places since more than one person could use a location to store items, but do you need a thing to have many owners?
If not, create a pivot model for the people_place and add a thing_id foreign key relationship to it, inferring the ownership from the pivot table.
